# wifiinfo.getSSID() returning 0x

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I am having a problem whit my function to connect to wireless network. 
I have a SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION Broadcastreceiver that I use to listen for completion or authentication failures. It is working just fine. 
Now I am getting some errors getting the SSID of the connected network.
CODE:

```
ublic class AuthWifi extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        ........
        case COMPLETED:
                    Log.i("SupplicantState", "Connected");
                    Log.d("WifiSSID",wifiinfo.getSSID()+" Actual SSID "+ClientManager.getSSID());
       .....
```

The log I am receiving on logcat is as folow *been Actual SSID the ssid that I have clicked and I am trying to connect to*:

```
D/WifiSSID﹕ 0x Actual SSID directest
```

I I look on the phone wifi configuration itself I see that i am connected to the wifi ...

As per android documentation I have read that if the SSID can not be utf-8 decoded it will return and hex string (looks like the case).

-1 How can I convert that hex string back to string to check if the network is connected ?
2- Why I am getting such results if the SSID has not any wrear characters ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is referance of wifiinfo into onReceive ?

Comment: I have declared the variable wifiinfo...
 mainWifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiinfo = mainWifi.getConnectionInfo();

Comment: it is onCreate on the main activity

Comment: public WifiManager mainWifi;
    public WifiInfo wifiinfo;

Comment: Putting wifiinfo inside onreceive works :D please post the answer the accept it. Thanks!!!

Comment: try `info.getBSSID ();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the reference of wifiinfo variable is correctly declared into onReceive Api.

The ouput seems to hv in-proper referance of variable.